# How to poweroff multiple linux machines in a single command or script?

Tags: linux, scripting, command, remote, shutdown

I have more than 10 Linux machines.  How may I power off all machines using a single script?

The password and user is the same for all of the machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many mays to do it.

One option is to use ssh key pairs instead of passwords to ssh without prompting for password. Then, you can do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

for server; do ssh $server 'halt; exit'; done
```

Usage:

```
./script.bash server1 server2 1.2.3.4
```

Or you can use a better approach with a tool like [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) or [pssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh)

Comment: foo,bar,base are hostnames ?

Comment: Sure it is servers names...

Comment: will ip address work instead of hostname?

Comment: Yes, it will work, for sure...

Comment: what will happend to this script if one of the machine is already in power off state ? will it break or continue executing next ?

Comment: It will produce an error, then continue executing next server

Comment: will this work? ' #!/bin/bash
servers = '123.123.123.123 111.111.111.111' 
for server; do ssh $server 'halt; exit'; done'

Comment: Maybe you can try by yourself and start experimenting ?!

Answer (score 5):

Try to use ansible.

Install ansible:

```
apt-get install ansible
```

Add your hosts to hosts file:

```
vim /etc/ansible/hosts
server1
server2
server3
```

Generate ssh key and add it on remote servers:

```
ssh-keygen
cat /etc/ansible/hosts | xargs -i ssh-copy-id {}
```

Run shutdown on servers:

```
ansible all -m shell -a "shutdown -h now"
```

You can check hosts availability by command before and after shutdown:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

[Source 1](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/introduction-to-ansible.html),
[Source 2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html#id3)

Answer (score 1):

Setup an ssh key for the user “shutdown”. If you look at /etc/passwd, this user’s default shell is /sbin/shutdown. So just logging in will execute the shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

I use fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/).  You'd write a python script and can then run it on remote systems.  It's quick and works pretty well for me for remote system administration.